# Android Studio 3.0 upgrade : Git and Subversion

Tags: android, git, android-studio, svn, android-studio-3.0

I recently:

- upgrade my Android Studio to ***3.0 stable channel***
- checkout my project hosted on SVN and which was on git 6 months ago.

My IDE is reading the project as it is on git and not on SVN **=>** I want to disconnect it from git and commit changes only on SVN .

***REM :*** I didn't face this behaviour when it was on Android Studio 2.3 stable channel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to change the version control settings in the `./.idea/vcs.xml` file:

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Change Git to SVN and reload the project in the IDE. I'm not sure if you can change that setting within the IDE settings itself, but this should be a simple change.

You can also try and simply delete the ".git" sub directory.